# Please Help "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code 2)"

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

im writing a C++ program that reads info about books from an external text file, stores the info in an array and writes a new file with the titles and prices of each book. at compile time there is no error but when I run the program I get a bunch of memory locations that pop up on the screen and an error

> "thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code 2)"

if it matters im using xcode on an intel mac. The code is below with a few screen shots of the problem. Thanks

The Code:

```
//main.cpp

include <iostream>
include <fstream>
include "Book.h"
include "textbook.h"
include "Name.h"
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

string title, authorf, authorl, publisher, isbn, subject;
int pages, i = 0, j = 0;
float price, rentalp;
char code;
static int bookCount = 0, textbookCount = 0;

ifstream file1, file2;
ofstream newFile;

file1.open("/Users/TVaughn/Documents/School Stuff/Fall 2012/CS 246/In Class Programs/Book/Book/Data.txt", ios::in); //Opening the data.txt file to read from.
newFile.open("/Users/TVaughn/Documents/School Stuff/Fall 2012/CS 246/In Class Programs/Book/Book/Title.txt", ios::out); //Creating a new file to store titles & prices of all the books.

book bookList[3];

while (!file1.eof()) {

    getline (file1, title, ',');
    getline (file1, authorf, ',');
    getline (file1, authorl, ',');
    getline (file1, publisher, ',');
    getline (file1, isbn, ',');
    file1 >> pages;
    file1.ignore();
    file1 >> price;
    file1.ignore();
    file1 >> code;
    file1.ignore(10, '\n');

    book b1(title, authorf, authorl, publisher, pages, isbn, price, code);
    bookList[i] = b1; //initalizing the first element of the array to b1
    newFile << "Title: " << bookList[i].getTitle() << "\n" << "Price: " << bookList[i].getPrice() << "\n\n"; //storing the title and price of all the books in a new file called titles.
    bookList[i].PrintBook();
    i++;
    bookCount++;

 }

 file1.close();

file2.open("/Users/TVaughn/Documents/School Stuff/Fall 2012/CS 246/In Class Programs/Book/Book/TextbookData.txt", ios::in); //Opening the TextbookData.txt file to read from.
textbook TbookList[2];

while (!file2.eof()) {

    getline (file2, title, ','); //retrieving info from data.txt and storing that info into variables so the variable may be passed as arguments in my textbook object b2.
    getline (file2, authorf, ',');
    getline (file2, authorl, ',');
    getline (file2, isbn, ',');
    file2 >> pages;
    file2.ignore();
    file2 >> price;
    file2.ignore();
    getline(file2, subject, ',');
    file2 >> code;
    file2 >> rentalp;
    file2.ignore(10, '\n');

    textbook b2(title, authorf, authorl, publisher, pages, isbn, price, code, subject, rentalp);
    TbookList[j] = b2; //initalizing the first element of the array to b2.
    newFile << "Title: " << bookList[j].getTitle() << "\n" << "Price: " << bookList[j].getPrice() << "\n\n";
    TbookList[j].PrintBook();
    j++;
    textbookCount++;

}

file2.close();
newFile.close();

cout << "Number of books: " << bookCount << "\nNumber of textbooks: " << textbookCount << endl;

book b3("C++ Data Structures", "Nell B.", "Dale", "Jones & Bartlett Publishers", 781, "9780763741587", 107.67, 'A'); //This line is used to test the exception handeling.

try {

    b3.setPrice(price);
    b3.setPages(pages);

}

catch (book::negativeNumber) {

    cout << "Negative price was entered \n\n" << "End of program \n";
}

return 0;
}




//book.h
#include <iostream>
#include "Name.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

class book
{
private:
    string title; 
    Name aurthor; 
    string publisher; 
    string ISBN; 
    int pages; 
    float price; 
    char code; 


public:
    class negativeNumber{};
    void setTitle(string);
    void setAurthor(string f, string l);
    void setPublisher(string);
    void setISBN(string);
    void setPages(int);
    void setPrice(float);
    void setCode(char);
    string getTitle();
    Name getAurthor();
    string getPublisher();
    string getISBN();
    int getPages();
    float getPrice();
    char getCode();
    void PrintBook();
    book(); //default constructor
    book(string, string, string, string, int, string, float, char); 
    ~book(); //Destructor


};
#endif




//Book.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Book.h" 
#include "Name.h"
using namespace std;

book::book() {

title = "Southern Charm";
Name::Name(); 
publisher = "Impact Publishers";
pages = 223;
ISBN = "234-232-10009045";
price = 14.99;
code = 'L';

}

book::book(string the_title, string f, string l, string the_pub, int page_num, string the_ISBN, float the_price, char the_c)
{
title = the_title;
//Name(f, l);
aurthor.setfName(f);
aurthor.setlName(l); 
publisher = the_pub;
pages = page_num;
ISBN = the_ISBN;
price = the_price;
code = the_c;

}

book::~book()
{

}

void book::setTitle(string t)
{
title = t;
}

void book::setAurthor(string f, string l)
{
aurthor.setfName(f);
aurthor.setlName(l);
}

void book::setPublisher(string pub)
{
publisher = pub;
}

void book::setISBN(string ISBN_num)
{
ISBN = ISBN_num;
}

void book::setPages(int p) {

if (pages > 0) 
    pages = p;
else
    throw negativeNumber();


}

void book::setPrice(float cost) {

if (price >= 0) //This is called exception handling. 
    price = cost;

    else
        throw negativeNumber();


}

void book::setCode(char c) {
code = c;
}

string book::getTitle() {
return title;
}


Name book::getAurthor(){

return aurthor;

}


string book::getPublisher() {

return publisher;
}

string book::getISBN(){

return ISBN;
}

int book::getPages() {

return pages;
}

float book::getPrice() {

return price;
}

char book::getCode() {

return code;
}

void book::PrintBook() {

cout << "Title: " << getTitle() << "\n" << "Aurthor: ";
getAurthor().printName();
cout << "Publisher: " << getPublisher() << "\n" << "Pages: " << getPages() << "\n" << "ISBN: " << getISBN() << "\n" << "Price: " << getPrice() << "\n" << "Code: " << getCode() << "\n \n \n";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read several lines from the file without checking if you've reached the end or errors have occurred.  You don't check if the file open has succeeded, then in your while loop you call `getline` several times without checking `eof` or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few points that jumped out at me:

1. My mantra: Thou shalt check reading worked after thy read.
2. Use of `std::ios_base::eof()` is only good to determine why the previous read failed.
3. You actual problem is: what happens if there are more than 3 books? (no need to answer: I know what happens...)
4. Expert programmers struggle with getting long functions right. Beginners stand no chance! Split your code into digestable and coherent chunks!

Fix the problems and retry.

Comment: I checked if all the reading worked by printing the variables that the info was stored in.(bookList[i].PrintBook). What functions do I need to break up? I didn't realize that they were long.

Comment: Everything interesting happens in `main()`. You'd rather have a function reading one book, called from `main()`, for example. This would slso point you quite clearly at the major problem I spotted (don't know if there are more: the code is too bug for me to keep track...).

Comment: also when I comment out the second while loop the program executes perfectly.

Comment: Try entering 10 books in the first loop. I'd be surprised if it works. Move the code reading a book into function and there is a much better chance to see the problem.

Comment: ok ill break down the main file. do you need me to include the .h and .cpp files that I included in this post?

Comment: the program will never take more than 3 books, thats why I set the array to take 3 objects. I wrote this program according to the guidelines my teacher gave us.

Comment: Well, checking `eof()` is a bad idea for starters: You want to check **after** reading that thing were successful, e.g., using `if (file) ..,`. If input fails for a different reason than hitting the end of the file you have an infinite loop. You should also guard against out of bounds access: I'm pretty sure that this is you bad access. Without seeing the input it's impossible to tell for sure but I would expect there is a wrong input or more books than expected.

Comment: Ive traced my problem to an infinite loop im having with my second while loop. I posted another question with the code that should be alot easier to read. thanks for your help!